# How can I fold or collapse multiple CSS rules in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I have several CSS rules that are related (ie 30 rules regarding a CSS Loading Spinner)

I would like to be able to lump all of these rules together so that I can collapse the section and be able to open that section if I need it again.

I know that I can collapse each individual rule but I don't know how I can do it for a bunch of rules that are listed together.  I thought that I could just add add the rules inside a pair of curly braces.

That worked as it let me collapse that set of curly brackets but the rules no longer worked.

Any ideas what I can do so that I can collapse large sets of rules and keep them in groups without the obvious solution of just keeping them in separate files.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
/* #region */
.css{}
/* #endregion */
```

or

```css
/* #region optional name for the section */
.css{}
/* #endregion */
```

This works for VS Code, haven't checked for other editors.

Edit: A code snippet to create a region for vs code:

```css
"css-region": {
    "body": [
        "/* #region ${1: name} */",
        "$0",
        "/* #endregion ${1: name} */",
    ],
    "description": "Create a css region section",
    "prefix": "#reg"
}
```

Comment: sublime!! (your post not the editor)

Answer (score 0):

I've taken to abusing `@media` queries to wrap them into blocks, and labeling the sections in comments. You can even nest blocks for more organization

```
/* tables */
@media {
    table {
        /* stuff */
    }
    td {
        /* stuff */
    }

    /* table images */
    @media {
        td img {
            /* stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

Most IDE's will let you collapse `{}` blocks, and the indentation also helps a lot visually